# Getting "Metadata generation failed" when building C# function app in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, azure

Starting with a C# function app created as a new project in VS2019 (16.4.1) and latest Azure libraries (Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools 16.4.457.38025) from VS Installer, it fails to build every time.

`C:\Users\myname\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.29\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(41,5): error : Metadata generation failed.`

Has anyone else been able to get this to work ?

Comment: Glad to hear that! You could accept it as answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in).

Answer (score 10):

To solve this issue, upgraded `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to last version(3.0.1).And delete the `netstandard1.0` folder:

```
"C:\Users\myname\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.29\build\netstandard1.0
```

Comment: Thanks Joey, that  fixed the problem !

Comment: Hi! I got the same error. But I'm failed when I typed ```"C:\Users\myname\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.29\build\netstandard1.0```. 
So first I want to make sure is that correct to change "myname" to my user name?

Comment: Then it shows ```dquote>```, I don't know what does it mean

Comment: Solved my problem. @Megan you have to replace "myname" with your PC-Username

Answer (score 3):

This error started occurring for me when I upgraded the "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" to 4.0.0 or above (unfortunately).
Staying with 3.0.13 allows it to compile without error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had 2 function Apps having the same Function name in the FucntionNameAttribute. By changing the names my Error get resolved

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, when locally building .net core "azure functions" apps with Visual Studio, you get these errors post-build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Metadata generation failed. MyProject.Api   C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.7\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets 44  
Error       Stack overflow.     MyProject.Api   C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.7\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets 44
```

This is a very frustrating reoccurring build error and the app will not run via the Functions CLI tools.

You may try:

- Rebooting system, close/reopen Visual Studio
- Manual steps of uninstall/reinstall .net frameworks or .net core
- Uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio

  - It may work for a while, then regress
- Completely reset Visual Studio
- Manual steps of deleting local nuget SDK items
- Upgrade your app's reference of "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" to the latest version
- The list goes on and on of things you may try to fix it...

Note: This error does not happen in VS Code (for me), mainly because we run the explicit command: dotnet build

So what fixed it?

- Uninstall all Visual Studio versions
- Uninstall all old Visual Studio build tools/TFS or Build tools/plugins/extensions (Jetbrains products included)
- Uninstall all .Net Core versions
- Uninstall all old SDKs
- Reviewing your installed "Programs and Features" list, be sure you uninstalled everything relating to SDKs, .Net Core, and Visual Studio.
- Install Visual Studio 2019

  - During Visual Studio 2019 install, on individual components tab, be sure this is check (should be by default):
    [image: individual components tab]

After install completes:

- Open Visual Studio -> Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio
- Be sure these are installed:

  - Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools (I have version: 16.5.236.49856)

    - Install instructions here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools
  - Microsoft Azure Tools (I have version: 2.9)

    - Search for installer or here's a link to 2.9: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51657

In the freshly installed Visual Studio instance, open your Functions App, build it, and press F5 (the app runs via the AzureFunctionsTools cli_x64.exe process):
[image: cli_x64.exe process]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

- be on your branch
- git clean -xdf  <-- this cleans the branch of all untracked files.  So be careful and save and commit all your files first.
- right click solution and clean
- right click solution and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of things. But you should have .Net Core 3.1 Runtime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should check all the parameters of your functions.
In my case the issue was related to the body parameter that was declared as dynamic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).